# Show that Cauchy sequences are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I want to show that Cauchy sequences are bounded without using the fact that Cauchy sequences are convergent sequences and convergent sequences are bounded.

**proof:**
Suppose $a_m$ is a Cauchy sequence, that is $\forall\varepsilon\gt0, \exists N\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$$m,n\gt N\implies |a_m-a_n|\lt \varepsilon$$

So we have $$-\varepsilon\lt a_m-a_n\lt\varepsilon$$
and
$$|a_n|-|\varepsilon|\le a_n-\varepsilon\lt a_m\lt a_n+\varepsilon \lt |a_n|+|\varepsilon|$$
$$|a_m|\lt |a_n|+\varepsilon$$

Am I on the right track at all? Can I then say that $M$ will be the bound for $a_m$ as:
$$M=\max\{a_1,...,|a_{n-1}|,|a_n|+\varepsilon\}$$Or am I making some incorrect assumption or something else?

Comment: Do you mean $$M=\max\{\vert a_1\vert, \dots, \vert a_n\vert+\varepsilon\}?$$

Comment: Let $\epsilon$ be a definite positive number, such as 1.

Comment: @P.Lawrence is it important that I choose a specific epsilon?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven yes I think so, oops

Comment: Where do the $\dots$ stop?

Comment: @TedShifrin well Severin asked if I meant that and it looked nicer, but I should probably make it clear that it stops at $a_n$ probably

Comment: Well, be sure! Note also that $|a_n|<|a_n|+\epsilon$.

Comment: @TedShifrin true, then $a_{n-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you break the sequence up into a finite sequence and the remaining infinite sequence. So, fill in the details in the following proof.

Proof: Given that $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, for $\varepsilon =1$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $j,k>N$, we have that $|a_j-a_k|<1$

Now split the sequence into a finite sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^N$ and the remaining infinite sequence $(a_n)_{n=N+1}^\infty$. Now use the theorem(use induction to prove it) that every finite sequence is bounded. So there exists a real number $M$ such that the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^N$ is bounded by $M$.

Now for the sequence $(a_n)_{n=N+1}^\infty$, we have the inequality that for every $j>N$ and fixed $k>N$ we have that $|a_j-a_k|<1$.

Take it from here to conclude that $|a_j|<1+|a_k|$. Then use your previous result that $(a_n)_{n=1}^N$ is bounded by $M$ to conclude that the entire sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded by $1+|a_k|+M$.

Comment: Do you mean "So there exists a real number $M$ such that the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\color{red}{N}}$ is bounded by $M$."?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins Yes. Sorry for the typo

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my initial approach? How would I use induction to prove every finite sequence is bounded?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins I was suggesting a shorter and cleaner proof I knew. As for proving that every finite sequence is bounded, here is a proof: Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be a finite sequence. Clearly $a_1$ is bounded by $|a_1|$. Now suppose inductively that the sequence $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ is bounded by some real number $M$. We have to show that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is bounded. Using our induction hypothesis we know that $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ is bounded by $M$. We also know that $a_n$ is bounded by $|a_n|$. Thus, the entire sequence $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is bounded by $M+|a_n|$.

Comment: That is pretty simple, thank you